# Модификация кода

Tags: c++, циклы

Даны натуральное число n и действительное число x. Необходимо вычислить значение  (x^(n^2))/2^n.

Как сделать это в одном цикле и без pow?

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int  n;
    double x, a = 1, b = 1;
    cout << "x=";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "n=";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
        b *= 2; 
        for (int j = 0; j < n * n; j++)
            a *= x;
           cout << "Result = " <<a/b;
}
```

Comment: Два цикла здесь вообще ни к чему. Приведённый код считает x^n^3, а не x^n^2. А какова реальная задача? (может попахивать расчётом члена ряда)

Comment: То же подозрение, что и у @MBo - что вы спрашиваете, не как забить гвоздь, а как держать при этом микроскоп... "Огласите весь список", т.е. всю задачу.

Comment: `2^n` можно вычислить как битовый сдвиг, `x^(n^2)` можно вычислить рекурсивно

Answer (score 2):

Если так критично именно один цикл...

```
double res = 1.0;
for(int i = 0; i < n*n; ++i)
{
    res *= x;
    if (i < n) res /= 2.0;
}
```

Но: куда быстрее такие вещи считать быстрым возведением в степень, типа

```
double qpow(double x, int e)
{
    double res = 1;
    for(;e;e>>=1)
    {
        if (e&1) res *= x;
        x *= x;
    }
}
```

Тогда

```
double res = qpow(x,n*n)/qpow(2,n);
```

Можно, конечно, поиграться и объединить два быстрых возведения в степень в один цикл... только вот есть подозрение, что вам нужно совершенно не это, что *вам кажется*, что вашу **полную** задачу нужно решать именно так...

P.S. Вариант `exp(n*n*log(x))`, хотя формально `pow` и не использует, я не рассматривал :)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы это вычислить можно вообще не использовать циклы.

```
exp(log(x)*exp(2*log(n))/exp(n*log(2))
```

либо так

```
exp(log(x)*n*n)/exp(n*log(2))
```